# Pinax Stripe - Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup one-off charges for my Django applications using Pinax-Stripe, but when i'm trying to create the charge I am receiving the error

> Request req_v8NSWneLebqYMK: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

I've succesfully added my secret + Publishable key in the settings.py and added the path to the webhook `path("payments/", include("pinax.stripe.urls")),`

I've ran `./manage.py init_customers` so existing users gets created as a customer.

My current test view is looks like this

```
charges.create(amount=decimal.Decimal("5.66"), customer=request.user.customer.stripe_id)
```

which is based on the code I've read in the documentation - https://pinax-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/ecommerce/

If it helps in any way, this is what the default django server prints when I try to create a charge - `"GET /dashboard/request/ HTTP/1.1" 500 102444`

Do I need to somewhere add a default credit card for testing purposes?

Comment: You're going to want to add a reusable `Source` to your `Customer` object before attempting to charge the customer. Check out https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers for some examples.

Comment: Would that mean I need to add a page with a form where a user add their details? I've been googling and can't seem to figure out if it's built in into the module

Comment: Yes, you'd want to collect that elsewhere. [Most of the details are optional](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) for the customer, and the [card details](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create) are documented as well.